# Microsoft Fake in Build server

Tags: msbuild, microsoft-fakes

I have a mstest project that uses Microsoft fake assembly. The test methods are executing fine in my local Visual studio ultimate. I never check in the fake dll in to repository (SVN), assuming that it will be created in the build server (Jenkins). Later I understood that the build server is using MSBuild.exe to build the solution and since MSBuild.exe doesn't know how to create the fake assembly, the build seems failing. Installing the Visual studio ultimate in the build server is the only one option or is there any other ways to execute the unit test (like check in the fake dll in to repository).

Answer (score 3):

You need Visual Studio Ultimate or Visual Studio Premium (if you are using a version later than Visual Studio 2012 Update 2) to be able to generate fakes. Also please make sure that your build script is using vstest.console.exe to execute tests. Fakes is not supported by MSTest.exe

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference to any Microsoft documentation where it states that Fakes is NOT supported with mstest.exe, and/or that Fakes IS supported with vstest.console.exe?